# Why I get different z values after adjusting the p values with post-hoc analysis?

Tags: r, self-study, z-score

I fitted my data in a GLMM model ("poisson" family) in R, and I got a z values of z value = 2.278. But after I put the model into post-hoc analysis ("Dunn" adjustment) with "emmeans", the z value became z value = -3.350. Why would the z value change?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Hayley. Welcome to CV. Could you add, perhaps, more info and possibly the data?

Comment: Welcome. I'm assuming that first z value is from the tests of the coefficients? Coefficients can be tricky to interpret, as they depend on your `contrasts` option and which coefficient it is. As already suggested, it would help to see the code you used for fitting the model, and the code and resulting output you have described.

Comment: @Hayley0830 , what you want to do to get good answers is provide a reproducible example.  This should be such that anyone can just copy and paste what you provide into R, and it runs and shows what you're experiencing.  You don't need to provide your real data. You can just make up some data that will work to show what you want it to show.  This way, any readers of the question can see exactly what you're talking about, and when you say e.g. "*z value = -3.350*".  See: [stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).